# How to save associated code with screenshots

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have to create a data set for a project I am doing. The task seems simple, I have to a create hundreds of screen shots of a GUI with one button taking a random position every time the code is run and save the image along with its CSS code. The css code should have the position of the button.

I can take the screen shot and save it with the button appearing on random location on the screen, but I am at a fail to save the CSS with location on the GUI.

I am using math random function to change the button location. Here is some code snippet.

```
<style>
        #container
       {
        width:400px;
        height:400px;
        background-color:red;
       }
       #btn 
       {
           position: absolute;
           color: black;
           width: 120px;
           height: 30px;
       }
    </style>
    <div id="container">
            <button id="btn">Click Me!</button>
    </div>



 Javascript code to pass random number to button position:
 <script>
            var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
            btn.style.top = Math.floor((Math.random() * 200) + 1) + "px";
            btn.style.left = Math.floor((Math.random() * 200) + 1) + "px";
 </script>
```

Saving a screenshot:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        //window.onload = function () {

            var takeScreenShot = function () {
                html2canvas(document.getElementById("container"), {
                    onrendered: function (canvas) {
                        var tempcanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                        var context = tempcanvas.getContext('2d');
                        context.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, 400, 400, 0, 0, 400, 400);
                        var png = ReImg.fromCanvas(document.getElementById('myCanvas')).toPng();
                        var link = document.createElement("a");
                        link.href = tempcanvas.toDataURL('image/png');   
                        link.download = 'screenshot.png';
                        link.click();

                    }
                });
            }
            var myVar = setInterval(takeScreenShot, 5000);
    </script>
```

Comment: I don't see the code for saving the image at all. And I'm also a bit confused by the topic being `javascript`. How can you control the image save from the client code without prompting it to the client?. My guess is that you're trying to save an html snapshot with every click... but until the code for saving the image is here, is hard to tell

Comment: I have added the code to save a screenshot. It prompts for a save for now, which I don't want. I also believe saving directly without a prompt with JS is not possible. I will have to use some other method.

Comment: Your original question was about not saving css... but not sure what css is not being saved. Can you clarify your question now with the whole code? If this is web application, and you're writing client code, there are not very good chances to save this without client prompt... if you don't want this, you need to generate the image on the server side and serve it to the client